# unable to launch facebook login page in Selenium

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I am testing a web app, that has facebook login icon. The HTML is like:

```
<div class="mylogin" align="right" id="fblogin" >
    <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" max-rows="1" onlogin="window.location.reload();" width="200" >
       <input type="button" />
    </fb:login-button>
</div>
```

When user clicks on facebook button, it launches the facebook login popup. I recorded those events using firefox IDE and playback, it is not launching the popup. However, if I execute the steps one by one, it was working.

The log recorded when executing manually one step at a time is as:

```
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | class=_4z_e img | |
[warn] Opening window '_blank', which is not a real window name. Randomizing target to be: selenium_blank79261
```

So, I thought reducing the speed while reply may work, but not.

Then I tried to export and execute through eclipse. The java code, (which if ofcourse not working) that the recorder gave is something like:

```
driver.get("xxx");
assertEquals("my title", driver.getTitle());
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: unknown strategy [class] for locator [class=_4z_e img]]
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
```

I tried all options I think of - like trying with other classes, ids around that area (that seems to be built dynamically by fb button).

I tried waiting between actions like thread.sleep, WebDriverWait (with various ids, classes)

```
WebDriverWait wdb=new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
WebElement element=wdb.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("_4z_f")));
```

it says: Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: u_0_1

Comment: What are you intending to achieve? Facebook has an extensive API that allows you to login etc, so why the need to do this through the website?

Answer (score 0):

Got this solved. The HTML with weird class names and ids seemed to be generated by facebook button and they are placed inside an iframe. When recording selenium recording the actions, it records the HTML element around the user action (like click).

When I change the lookup object to the main div, (facebook button as a whole) and execute the test, its working.

To answer Arran's question, I am building an automation test suite using Selenium for the website. I'm not sure if there is any other approach. Please suggest if any.